# How to release the memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, gtk

I have this code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *fixed, *button;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 400, 400);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Test");
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", 
                     G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);
    gtk_widget_show(fixed);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("click");
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button, 30, 30);
    gtk_widget_show(button);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to release the memory, but fail. Maybe someone to modify this code such that the memory to be released? 
I read about memory management in GTK and I understand in largely how it works, but fail to release the memory...

I understand how these functions works gtk_widget_destroy(), g_object_ref_seek(), g_object_ref() and g_object_unref() and I don't want to receive the references at these functions or at documentation, I wish to modify someone this code such that the memory to be released.

Thank!

Comment: Which memory do you intend to free ? There's nothing in particular in this code that you'd need to release.

Comment: How do you conclude that the memory is **not** released? What problem are you solving, exactly?

Comment: I want to release the memory occupied of window, fixed and button variable. I concluded that the memory is not released when I run the code with valgrind.

Comment: Large libraries like GTK (and the underlying GDK, Xlib, cairo, pango, FreeType, etc.) are complex to analyze using memory profilers because they make use of pool allocators which reuse freed objects for later allocations of the same kind. This often leads tools like valgrind to report false memory leaks. A more robust test is a primitive one: create and destroy a window in a loop with a large number of iterations, and watch out for the memory usage of your process. If it keeps growing throughout the test, you have a memory leak. If it begins growing, but then levels off, everything is fine.

Comment: I executed the application at which I work. Initially the application occupy 12mb. I open more windows and the application occupy 22mb. After what I closed all windows, the application occupy 16mb. Why the application occupy with 4mb more? It's fine or I have a memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have alredy connected gtk_main_quit to the window. When the window is destroyed, all of her child widgets are destroyed too.

Comment: In my example when the window is destroyed, the memory on which the window deals her is released together with the memory occupied of fixed and button variable?

Comment: I know that if a widget is destroyed that not means that the memory of the widget is released.

Comment: The first line in your main function is the declaration of three pointers to the type GtkWidget. After that you use `window = gtk_window_new`. I am pretty sure that this function returns the memory adress where the GtkWidget is allocated. If you alredy know how to manipulate pointers, this is something like that: `*window = &your_widget`. The function `gtk_widget_destroy` should be like the `free(*pointer)` function in C since this is the choice for release memory. Notice that the `free(*pointer)` function and the `gtk_widget_destroy(*pointer)` fucntion have the same syntax.